# Selenium Python Input em um teclado virtual

Tags: html, python, selenium-webdriver

Eu estou enfrentando um problema com selenium, que é fazer um login em uma pagina, mas o problema é que quando pego o elemento (name) ou pelo elemento (ID)do campo ele me retorna erro falando que aquele elemento não exite.

esse é o código HTML.

**INPUT USER**

```
<input name="txtUsuario" class="box" style="WIDTH: 100px" onkeydown="return onTecla(event)" onkeypress="return onTecla(event)" onfocus="return FieldClick(this);" type="text" maxlength="13"></input>
```

**INPUT PASSWORD**

```
<input name="pswSenha" class="box" id="pw" style="WIDTH: 50px" onkeydown="return onTecla(event)" onkeypress="return onTecla(event)" type="password" maxLength="99"></input>
```

tudo isso é dentro de um tag `<div>` e dentro dessa tag tem `<table>`, `<tbody>`, `<tr>`

uso esse código

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
browser = webdriver.Ie()
browser.get(URL)
browser.maximize_window()
elem = browser.find_element_by_name('txtUsuario')
elem.send_keys('usuario')
```

esse é o erro que ele me retorna

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to find element with css selector == [name="txtUsuario"]
```

alguém tem uma ideia de como resolver isso ?

Comment: coloca o código que tu ta usando, ou o esse trecho, pq só com isso não da pra te ajudar

Comment: pronto editei o post

Comment: Só pode ser com IE? isso é alguma restrição do site?

Comment: Sim, só com o IE ele funciona. tem restrições ele não funciona com o Chrome e nem com o Firefox

Comment: tenta colocar um `time.sleep(10)` depois do `browser.maximize_window()`, pode ser que o elemento não tenha sido carregado. caso não seja isso tenta abaixar as configurações de segurança do ie de alto para médio

Comment: outra opção é você ver se esse elemento esta dentro de uma `iframe`

Comment: eu tentei colcoar para o nivel de segunraça medio ele me retorna isso   selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: Unexpected error launching Internet Explorer. Protected Mode settings are not the same for all zones. Enable Protected Mode must be set to the same value (enabled or disabled) for all zones.

Comment: eu pensei nisso antes de um iframe, mas ele não está dentro de um iframe.

Comment: coloccou o `time.sleep`,  por mais besta que pareça, pode acontecer de não carregar todos os elementos. Já enfrentei muito isso.

Comment: [aparentemente tem o mesmo problema que você](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23770843/cannot-find-any-elements-in-selenium-using-internet-explorer-driver/27693696)

Comment: coloquei time.sleep() sim coloque até 20s mesmo assim não foi.

Comment: eu tentei diminir o nivel de segunraça mas ele me da erro o selenium

Comment: você consegue qualquer outro elemento? tem como passar a url?

Answer (score -3):

Tente localizar o elemento desta maneira:
elem = wait.until(expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME,"txtUsuario")))

Estou tendo dificuldades para acessar um site que também utiliza o modo de compatibilidade do IE e também usa um teclado virtual.